# Vaadin: Using an image as a button

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin7

I wanted to use a image as a button. I got it working, but it is not very well made, please take a look at the screenshot. As you can see the Button itself is a lot bigger than the image, but I wanted it to be as big as the image:

[image]

The actual Button is bigger than the Image. The goal here is that there is nothing but the image to click. How can I achieve this? Here is the code ofthe button on the screenshot:

```
 Button testButton = new Button();
 String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 testButton.setIcon(new FileResource(new File(basepath + "/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/img/Button.png")));
 loginForm.addComponent(testButton);
```

I know that

```
testButton.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK)
```

makes the button invisible, but unfortunately that does not adjust the size of the button, just the visbility..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add a click listner to an image instead of using a button.

```
Image image = new Image(null, new ClassResource("/images/button-img.jpg");
image.addClickListener(e -> System.out.println("click"));
image.addStyleName("my-img-button");
```

And add this css, I use the @Stylesheet annotation to add in CSS.

```
.my-img-button {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You can fix that with a little css

Comment: works fine too - can I use the ClickListeners of Vaadin here? image.addClickListener(new ClickListener()  { ... } )); doesn't work here..

Comment: Yes you can do this, be aware that vaadin has more than one ClickListener, your code may still have a different one imported.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I marked your answer as the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
  Button button = new Button();
  button.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
  button.setIcon(new ClassResource("/images/button-img.jpg"));
  button.addClickListener(e -> System.out.println("click"));
```

Maybe you have additional css defined?

Maybe your button is contained in a layout with a fixed height?

Also make sure that your button has no width/height configured, so it can automatically adjust its size to that of the icon image.

[image: button]

The next problem you'll probably run into is the focus border:

[image: focus]

Another approach would be to use a layout click listener, and add you own mouse-over/hover/focus styling via CSS.

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(new Image(null, new ClassResource("/images/test.png")));
layout.addLayoutClickListener(e -> System.out.println("click"));
```

Comment: You are right, there is some additional CSS which causes that. I found the exact attribute which does it, but I can't affect or change it, because it only occurs in the style.css, which is generated by the framework. I cannot make change in the CSS -file itself, but this can't be found in the scss files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With Vaadin 14:

```
Image img = new Image("src");
Button testButton = new Button(img);
```

Quite straightforward.